# Problem in starting the thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I m using Java and i m trying below piece of code

```
public RunnableThread(String threadName){

     thread = new Thread(this,threadName);
     System.out.println(thread.getName());
     thread.start();
     boolean status=thread.isAlive();
}
```

but when i m checking the status of the thread its returning me false.

I m not getting what could be the issue.

Thanks for the suggestion in advance.

Actually my run() method has much code to execute.

My main() method has below piece of code as some of its part
    JumboScrapeThread jumbThread = new JumbocrapeThread("jubmThread");
    Thread scraper = new Thread(jumbThread,"scraper");
        scraper.start();

As we know when we call thread.start() ,it internally call run() method.
but i m getting the problem in starting the thread,so my run() method is not getting called.

I m using the thread with sellinium so is there any possibility that i m getting issue because of it..?

Comment: What does the run() method do?

Comment: what do you do inside the thread.run(). Maybe it finishes before you retrieve the isAlive value?

Comment: Now i m getting the status of thread as alive but as we know the start() internally calls the run() method,but in my case run method is not getting called.can you suggest me for this?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a classic race condition: calling `start()` only *begins* the process of creating and eventually running a new thread, and the `isAlive()` is called before that process has reached the stage where the thread is officially considered "started" (or, possibly, after it has finished running).

Answer (score 1):

The thread ends as soon as the `run()` method ends, hence the status of the thread will probably be 'false' by the time the `isAlive()` method is called, although the JVM makes no guarantees about this (a so-called race condition as to whether it returns true or false). You should put something in the `run` method.

Comment: hello chris,Actually my run() has lots of stuff to execute.but the thing is that nw i m getting the status of thread as alive but my run() method is not getting executed.i have set breakpoints in run() method but while debugging also its not going to run() method.

Answer (score 1):

THats because Thread needs either a Runnable or a Thread as input and i am not sure whats the type of your RunnableThread and whether you have overridden the run() method.

If its empty, the thread would have finished execution, inwhich case the alive returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because the thread has started and finished before you call `isAlive()`. The JVM makes no guarantees about the order in which threads are executed, unless you put in explicit synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronization to wait for your thread to start completely.

**Code**

```
public class Main {

    static class RunnableThread implements Runnable {

        private Thread thread;
        private Object waitForStart = new Object();

        public RunnableThread(String threadName) {

            thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
            System.out.println(thread.getName());


            synchronized (waitForStart) {
                thread.start();
                try {
                    waitForStart.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
                boolean status = thread.isAlive();
                System.out.println(status);
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            synchronized (waitForStart) {
                waitForStart.notifyAll();
            }

            // Do a bunch of stuff
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }

            System.out.println("Thread finished.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableThread thread = new RunnableThread("MyThread");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Andrew..i have tried your code in my program.now my thread status is alive but now the run method is not getting called still.

Comment: @Saggy I'll be more than happy to help. Would you mind updating your question with the code surrounding you spawning the thread and the first few lines of your run method. I have a feeling your run method is getting locked in synchronization. You can use pastebin.com and just reply in the comments if you'd like to keep your original question pure.